# How to get sent message immediately with Send & Wait for Reply Widget - Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

Hey Twilio Developer Evangelists, is there any way to get the sent message immediately with Send & Wait for Reply Studio Widget. It exposes three options:

[image: Sent & Wait for Reply Widget]

1. Reply
2. No reply
3. Delivery Fails

But I am specifically looking for the `Delivered` option so, I can do something without waiting for a reply. I do want to wait for the reply but I also want to get the sent message right after it's sent. Is there any way I can achieve this? With webhooks to receive the sent message OR any other way?

With programmable messaging, Twilio gives an option to track the status of the sent message with `statusCallback` parameter but I do not see any option to provide a status callback in the studio widget.

Comment: I've answered that there's no way to do this in Studio, but can I ask what you are trying to achieve with this? Maybe there is some other way around it?

Comment: Hello Philnash, we have a chat application in which we show all messages in real-time. So I was looking for a way to receive the outbound SMS from `Send & Wait for Reply` widget right after it's sent/delivered.

Comment: I think I'm a little more confused here! Perhaps you can email me with an description and I can try to help out. My email is philnash [at] twilio [dot] com.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no way, that I know of, to achieve this in Studio. There is also no way to set a general statusCallback URL for outbound messages from a number.